# Access to inherited function not possible in PHP

Tags: php, function, inheritance

i try to illustrate articles about PHP and have built with this structure:

Article

-- ChildArticle

I now want to access a function in the ChildArticle class that is inherited from the Article class.

Here is my Article class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Article;
use PDO;
class Articles
{
private $id;
private $name;
private $cid;
private $ordernumber;
private $description;
private $descriptionLong;
private $childArticles;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCid()
{
    return $this->cid;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOrdernumber()
{
    return $this->ordernumber;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDescriptionLong()
{
    return $this->descriptionLong;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getChildArticles()
{
    return $this->childArticles;
}

function readChildArticles(PDO $pdo){
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT articleID as id, ordernumber FROM `s_articles_details` WHERE ordernumber LIKE :ordernumberWOD AND ordernumber NOT LIKE :ordernumber"
    );
    $stmt->execute([
        'ordernumberWOD'=>$this->ordernumber.".%",
        'ordernumber'=>$this->ordernumber
    ]);
    $this->childArticles = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"App\\Article\\ChildArticle");

    }


}
```

Here is my ChildArticle class:

```
class ChildArticle extends Articles
{

}
```

Now I want to read the order numbers of the child articles:

```
    foreach ($article->getChildArticles() as $child){
        echo "Child: {$child->getOrdernumber()}<br>";
    }
```

My readChildArticles function:

```
function readChildArticles(PDO $pdo){
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        "SELECT articleID as id, ordernumber FROM `s_articles_details` WHERE ordernumber LIKE :ordernumberWOD AND ordernumber NOT LIKE :ordernumber"
    );
    $stmt->execute([
        'ordernumberWOD'=>$this->ordernumber.".%",
        'ordernumber'=>$this->ordernumber
    ]);
    $this->childArticles = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,"App\\Article\\ChildArticle");

}
```

My output is like:

```
Child: 
Child:
and so on
```

if i get the ordernumber via $child->ordernumber, it works.

Why doesn't my ChildArticle class take over the function exactly like the parameters?

And can you give me a hint how I can solve the problem or where I can read about it?

thx :)

Comment: and where do you set `$ordernumber`?

Comment: Can you show the `getChildArticles()` function?

Comment: @treyBakeI read the numbers from a database

Comment: It works, so long as `$ordernumber` has a value... see: https://3v4l.org/AfZsl

Comment: @Rudi I see, how do you assign it? Via a `__construct()` ?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes there is my getChildArticles dunction

Comment: @Rudi No, what you posted is `readChildArticles()`.  That is not the same as `getChildArticles()`

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm so excited...
getChildArticles is only a getter, the article Class has a parameter $childArticles = []. The readChildArticles read the childs from the database and fill the array with the created childArticle objects. the getChildArticles return the array with this childs

Comment: @naththedeveloper thx thanks that makes sense, but then why does it work with  $child->ordernumber and not about the getter? so the parameters have a value already

Comment: @Rudi That doesn't clarify anything.  Where do you call `readChildArticles()`?  And you still haven't shown `getChildArticles()`

Comment: This can be significantly reduced and simplified: read one instance of a `ChildArticle` using your PDO method, then `var_dump` that and try to gets its order number. If that doesn't work, concentrate on that part, constructing an instance via PDO. If that *does* work, the problem is elsewhere…

Comment: The problem is probably that `$ordernumber` is `private`. PDO sets the property *on the child*, but the property that the parent tries to read has a different scope (because `private`).

Comment: @PatrickQ i wanted to simplify it a bit -> the getChildArticles() is in my article class.

i call the readChildArticles() in my main.php whit a foreach loop:

        foreach ($article->getChildArticles() as $child){
            echo "Child: {$child->ordernumber}<br>";
        }

Comment: @deceze That's it! with public $ordernumber; in my article Class it works -> would you do it with public too, or is that bad code?

Comment: @Rudi if you expect to inherit the Article class, then it may make sense to use `protected` modifier instead of public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way PDO constructs the object: it creates an instance of the class (`ChildArticle`), then sets all the columns as properties on it. Since `$ordernumber` is `private`, this creates a separate property in each class, i.e. `Article::$ordernumber` and `ChildArticle::$ordernumber` are two entirely separate properties. The method in `Article` tries to access `Article::$ordernumber`.

Make the property at least `protected`, or change the way in which you instantiate the class.

If you don't have a good reason for using separate properties and getters, you may as well consider making the property `public` and getting rid of the getter method.

Comment: many thanks :)
i thought you should always query parameter with setter and getter and not directly?

Comment: Most of the time that's overkill. If you have getters *and* setters which don't do anything but get and set the value, then it's as good as having `public` properties in the first place. If you have only getters, you at least have a read-only object; but of how much use that is in practice is questionable too.

Comment: The trouble with PHP is that you can hardly switch from a public property to a getter/setter (which *does* something important) later transparently. In other languages you could add a getter/setter while keeping the `$foo->bar = ...` syntax unchanged. Soooo… try to anticipate your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for taking the time for me *-*